# Ensure WebSockets only connecting from known domain

Tags: validation, authentication, dns, websocket

How can I make sure only a script hosted on a specific list of domains is allowed to connect to my WebSocket application?

Or to prevent opinion based closevotes, is there a state-of-the-art or native way?

I do not intend to implement user authentication.

Comment: Some years later I think I was asking  about CORS but not sure :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanism for this with WebSocket is the `origin` header.

This HTTP header is set by browsers to the domain of the host that served the HTML that contained the JavaScript which opened the WebSocket connection.

A WebSocket server can inspect the `origin` header during the initial opening handshake of the WebSocket protocol. The server can then only allow proceeding of the connection if the `origin` matches a known whitelist.

The header cannot be modified from JavaScript, and all browsers are *required* by the RFC6455 specification to include it.

**Caution: a *non-browser* WebSocket client can of course fake the `origin` header to any value it likes.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need a non-fakeable solution.. I'll mix my own idea of a server-to-server handshake before the websocket with your solution.

Comment: You did ask for the "standard approach", which is described in the answer. Non-fakeable: one approach is to set a cookie on the HTML serving HTTP connection, and forward that to the WebSocket connection.

Comment: Stealing a cookie by man-in-the-middle: not if you run TLS. But yes, if you don't authenticate, then a bot can harvest them.

Comment: when a bot visits the site using TLS he get's a cookie... bot can connect.

Comment: You can use TLS client certificates to authenticate the client. Otherwise, there is no way: non-fakeable and non-authenticated is a contradiction

Comment: I can't authenticate by user/client. But I could add captcha. It's not a contradiction. But an "authentication" which does not authenticate origin is kinda useless.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear from the question. I suggest you improve on this first.

Answer (score 1):

@oberstet gave you the right answer.

If you are worried about bots or programmatic HTTP agents, then you are going to have a bad time. Everything in a HTTP request can be spoofed. Your only option is to use cookies to attach a token with limited time validity that certify the user went through an allowed website to get that script. Get that cookie in the WebSocket handshake and decide if you allow it or not.

E.g.: When a user visit your site, or one of your sites, return a cookie with a symmetrically encrypted token based on the user IP address, User-Agent header, and Origin header; when the user initiates a WebSocket connection, if it is in the same 2nd domain, it will send the cookie, then if the data adds up allow the connection, otherwise, reject it.  If the WS is in another domain, then you will have to forget about cookies and rely on a web socket message once the connection is established to check the validity of the connection.